# Connecting Method Issue by using Java

Tags: java

I was trying write a code using Method(). This is my first year on Computing Science and sometimes I am struggling a bit. My aims are:
1- Taking user input
2- Calculate the values
3- print it (by using Method)

Here is my code;

```
import java.util.*;
class testMethod {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter First Number ");
        a = kb.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter Second Number");
        b = kb.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter Third Number");
        c = kb.nextInt();

        int total = getCuboid(a, b, c);
        System.out.println("The volume of a cuboid is: " + answer);
    }

    public static getCuboid(int a, int b, int c){ 
        int answer = (a*b*c);
        return answer;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I want to run that program. but I cannot run it. My main aim is I want to use the Method in that case. Unfortunately, I cannot fix it when I use the Method

Comment: What happens when you try to run the code? What is stopping you?

Comment: Try running the code and fixing the compiler errors.

Comment: @dustinos3 "testMethod.java:19: error: invalid method declaration; return type required" that was a error i got. Firstly, I put System.out.println("The volume of a cuboid is: " + answer); inside of main and delete it "int answer = (a*b*c);" then I changed the "a = kb.nextInt(); to int a = kb.nextInt()"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not returning anything from the getCuboid method. You need to give the methoda return type as follows:

```
public static int getCuboid(int a, int b, int c ){
return a*b*c;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you meant it...

```
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter First Number ");
        int a = kb.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter Second Number");
        int b = kb.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter Third Number");
        int c = kb.nextInt();

        int total = a * b * c;

        try {
            Method method = PrintStream.class.getDeclaredMethod("println", String.class);
            try {
               method.invoke(System.out, "The volume of a cuboid is: " + total);
            } catch (IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @user11193293. "shelholmes221" fix my problem. :)